# Need to sync between two laptops via an external hard drive

Tags: windows-7, sync

I have 2 laptops and I want to sync certain folders on those laptops via an external hard drive. 
For example: my music folder. I want it backed up on the external hard drive, but for each laptop to have a local copy too, and I want each laptop updated once one of the laptops makes a change to the folder and I connect the other laptop to the hard drive.

Are there any free programs that can help me do this?

I run Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=C26EFA36-98E0-4EE9-A7C5-98D0592D8C52&displaylang=en) should work great. It is a program called SyncToy 2.1 that is made by Microsoft for this purpose (and its free).

Comment: Can you add more detail to your answer - like what you are linking to and why it solves the problem.

Comment: @ChrisF Apologies for not doing that.